# (JAVA)Why i have no results?Have something wrong in the main class?I can't find that

Tags: java

```
package Java_class;
```

//abstract father class,have getnum() and show();

```
import java.util.*;
abstract class class1{
    final int low=200;
    final int high=3000;
    protected abstract int getlabel();
    protected abstract void show();
    int[] dig;
    int sum=0;
    protected int getnum() {
        int num =(int)(Math.random()*(high-low)+low);
        return num;
    }
}
```

//child class,to return different number to show their label;

```
class object1 extends class1{
    protected int getlabel() {
        dig=new int[50]; 
        for(int i=0;i<50;i++) {
            dig[i]=getnum();
        }
        int max=dig[0];
        for(int i=0;i<dig.length;i++) {
            while(dig[i]>0) {
                sum+=dig[i]%10;
                dig[i]/=dig[i];
            }
            if(sum>max) {
                max=sum;
            }
        }
        return max;
    }
    protected void show() {
        System.out.println("Senior Manager");
    } 
}
```

// the main class,to create the object and show its name and label;

```
public class test1 {

    public static void play(class1 stf) {
        int label=stf.getlabel();
        System.out.println(label);
        stf.show();
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        object1 player= new object1();
        play(player);
    }  
}
```

the codes run and show nothing....why...

Comment: First start by following java naming conventions. Class names go UpperCase. Then you use names that mean something. Calling your child class "object1" is like meaning ... nothing. This doesnt tell the reader anything about .

Comment: Beyond that, "not showing anything" sounds wrong. You should get some print statements. Really, nothing?

Comment: My fault, my codes are long so i code something like that, forget the class name....and,i really get nothing....

Comment: @蔡王辉 The better way of saying "I get nothing" is that the program never terminates.

Comment: You may also want to learn [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's your problem:

```
while (dig[i] > 0) {
    sum += dig[i] % 10;
    dig[i] /= dig[i];
}
```

After the first iteration `dig[i]` is always equal to `1`. Because of the third line. So you get an infinite loop. Such mistakes are easy to find if you use a debugger instead of just running your code.

Comment: Just a minor detail: `dig[i]` cannot be zero, because `class1.low = 200`, which is the smallest possible random number generated by `getnum()` method.

Comment: ohhhhhh! i'm stupid, thanks bro!

Comment: @JaroslawPawlak okay, thanks, I did not actually view all of his code, I simply used a debugger.

Answer (score -1):

```
 while(dig[i]>0)
```

it can be endless loop.
Use debug on your methods and u see it.